# Can I use a JavaScript variable within Server-Side Tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to pass a JavaScript variable to a server-side tag to avoid a post-back.

I'd like the solution to look something like this:

Code Behind:

```
Public Property NameCollection As Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

JavaScript that I wish to have:

```
$('#<%= txtIDNumber.ClientID %>').change(function(){
    var idNumber = $('#<%= txtIDNumber.ClientID %>').val();
    var lblName = $('#<%= lblName.ClientID %>');

    <%If NameCollection.ContainsKey(idNumber) Then %>
        lblName.html('<%=NameCollection(idNumber)%>');
    <%Else%>
        lblName.html('<span class="error">Not a User</span>');
    <%End If %>
});
```

These server-side tags work properly if I hard-code the idNumber (say '1234' or something), so I know my object/code itself is working properly, but is there a way to get it to recognize/pass the JavaScript variable here?

**Extra Info:**
I do have a functional work-around, but it is the ugly and inefficient method of looping through all the items in the collection, so I would like to know how to do this better if there is a way to. Thanks for help. :)

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:**

This is my current work-around. Very ugly because I can't figure out a way to just use the idnumber as an index instead of looping through all items. The NameCollection is already loaded with the data on the ASP.NET page load event, so while I'm not sure what's going on in the background with server-side tags, I assumed the data should exist in that object statically the way it was at the last call to the server, but that the *snapshot* of that data physically existed on the client-side (it would have to to avoid post-backs, right?)? Thus, I should be able to avoid having to talk to the server here since I am only accessing data that should already be on the client side? Correct me (nicely please) if I am wrong, since I'm not an expert on JavaScript or web programming in general and I have been able to find very few decent references on server-side tags.

```
$('#<%= txtIDNumber.ClientID %>').change(function(){
    var idnumber = $('#<%= txtIDNumber.ClientID %>').val();
    var lblName = $('#<%= lblName.ClientID %>');
    var tempJSKey = '';
    var tempJSValue = '<span class="error">Not a Member</span>';

    <%If Not NameCollection Is Nothing Then%>
        <%For Each kvp As System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In NameCollection %>
            tempJSKey = '<%=kvp.Key %>';
            if (tempJSKey == idnumber)
            {
                tempJSValue = '<%=kvp.Value%>';
            }
        <%Next%>
    <%End If%>
    lblName.html(tempJSValue);
});
```

Comment: what javascript variable are you referring to?

Comment: I think you should use AJAX to communicate this way.

Comment: var idnumber, which I am trying to use inside the <% %>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do what you want here is with Ajax or forms.

```
$('#<%= txtIDNumber.ClientID %>').change(function(){
    var idNumber = $('#<%= txtIDNumber.ClientID %>').val();
    var lblName = $('#<%= lblName.ClientID %>');

    $.ajax({
       "url": "YourServerURLHere",  
       "data":{
           "idNumber":idNumber
       },
       "success": function(data)
       {
          lblName.text(data);
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to do this, but I am confused, is it doing a post-back and am I supposed to be getting the data out of Request.QueryString or am I writing some sort of server-side function to handle the ajax request? Kind of a whole different approach, but it seems like maybe ajax could be used to pull data straight from a database?

Comment: You need to write some server code to handle your request. It is similar to what happens when you open a web page but instead of directly displaying the results the success function handles the request. You would get idNumber from the Request object (I believe it is Request.QueryString("idNumber") jquery.ajax defaults to "get"). Then you would process the idNumber and return (Response obj) the data to the client. The success method then handles the returned data. You cannot directly access the DB you still need .Net for that.

Comment: http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/ajax-basics-with-jquery-in-asp.net/ might help a little there are various tutorials on using .Net with ajax and you setup may vary depending on if you are using MVC

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't mix server side code with javascript.

The parsing happens on the server before it even passed to the client.

If you want to use the client id on the server for some reason use:

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```

For example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtIDNumber" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confused as to how ASP works.  When you have `<% anything %>` that's evaluated on the server, before anything ever reaches the client/browser.  Once it has been evaluated, the evaluated version of the page is sent to the client; from that point on `<% anything %>` is completely meaningless.

In light of that, hopefully you can understand why throwing all the ASP in the world in to your JS won't help at all: it's already "too late" by the time JS code is involved.

If you want to send data back to the server, you have two options:

1) traditional HTML forms

2) an AJAX request

both have their pros/cons, and both require you to create submit point on your server, but going in to full details is beyond the scope of this answer.  Suffice it to say, read up on handling form submissions and handling AJAX requests with ASP and you should find lots of material available.

Comment: Whoops, my mistake (they look similar).  Luckily I only had to change six characters of my answer :-)

Comment: I guess I am confused? I am aware I can't get new data from the server, but I have all the data loaded into my dictionary object ahead of time (on the page load event) so the data should just be sitting there. I can loop through the dictionary in a for each loop, so I know the data is loaded properly. I was hoping there was a way to index this data (as opposed to inefficiently looping though all items), either by the way I attempted above, or by assigning the dictionary values to a JavaScript variable and then indexing that, however I have not figured out either method yet.

Comment: You're mixing ASP and JS.  Here's the order of operation 1) you type in your URL in your browser and hit enter 2) your server runs your ASP code, generates an HTML file, and sends it back to your computer 3) your computer reads that HTML file and loads it 4) your "onLoad" JS runs.  It is *impossible* to pass any information from the JS code to the ASP code because the JS code is running on the user's computer, whereas the ASP code is running on the server.  The only way to send information back to the server/ASP code is to make a new request (either a form submission or an AJAX one).

Comment: Now, your last comment sounds like something different from what you described in your question.  If all you're trying to do is access some ASP information (like say a string that results from `NameCollection(idNumber)`) in your JS, then that part is easy; just throw: `var myVariable = '<%=NameCollection(idNumber)%>';` inside a script tag and you'll have a JS variable with that string (although if you want to get technical that value gets written to the HTML page by the ASP, your browser loads it, and the JS gets the value from the HTML page, not the server).

Comment: var myVariable = '<%=NameCollection(idNumber)%>';

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do! I can't get it to work.

I understand that I can't load new data into the object, but I don't need to, the data is already in there from the get go. I load the dictionary in the page load event of ASP.NET, not in onload of JavaScript. The String data is already there, and it is all I want. The problem I am running into is that the JavaScript variable idnumber is not recognized inside the server-side tags <% %>. Do you know how I'd get around this?

Comment: "the JavaScript variable idnumber is not recognized inside the server-side tags <% %>." - with all due respect, that comment shows that you're not reading/understanding my answer, my comments or any of the other answers posted.  Let me try again: YOU CAN NEVER  ACCESS A JAVASCRIPT VARIABLE INSIDE ASP ("<%%>") CODE.  This misunderstanding is emblematic of a larger issue (the distinction between "server-side" code and "client-side" code), which will severely limit you as a web developer until you "grok" it .  Unfortunately I just can't explain that to you in the depth you need in these comments.

Comment: P.S. Sorry to "shout" (with the caps), but this is a pivotal thing you need to understand to do web development.  Perhaps these links can help where I couldn't: 1) http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/aspnet/threads/29366/what-is-server-and-client-side-code 2) http://www.codeconquest.com/the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-front-end-and-back-end/ 3) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model

Comment: Okay, well my "misunderstanding" was a direct copy and paste of your comment, so I'm sorry it offended you so much? I think you are also misunderstanding what I am trying to accomplish. Just for clarity: I AM NOT TRYING TO DO A POSTBACK, I AM NOT TRYING TO GET DATA FROM THE SERVER. I ALREADY UNDERSTAND I CAN'T DO THAT, NOR IS THAT WHAT I AM ATTEMPTING TO DO. Better?

Comment: I wasn't offended, as I tried to clarify (but it's hard to communicate tone in text).  But look: myself, Kimtho6, scrappedcola, and gdoron have all taken time out of our busy days (me more than most) to try and help you.  Rather than listen to what any of us are telling you, you're choosing to argue with us.  As I've said (multiple times now), your fundamental problem is a misunderstanding of the client-server relationship, and until you acknowledge and attempt to rectify that, no amount of berating us (or otherwise spending your time here on Stack Overflow) will help you.

Comment: (But listening to the people trying to help you, eg. by reading those links I took time to provide you, just might; crazier things have happened.)

Answer (score 0):

You cant pass javascript to a serverside "element" but why dont you just change your code to this:

```
$('#<%= txtIDNumber.ClientID %>').change(function(){

    var lblName = $('#<%= lblName.ClientID %>');

    <%If NameCollection.ContainsKey(txtIDNumber.ClientID) Then %>
        lblName.html('<%=NameCollection(txtIDNumber.ClientID)%>');
    <%Else%>
        lblName.html('<span class="error">Not a User</span>');
    <%End If %>
});
```

Comment: This was my first thought too. Unfortunately, the Text property is still whatever it was last time the server knew about it, not the value that triggered the change event. The ClientID would need some sort of equivalent to .val(), but there's the crux of the problem again.